Realize Instances solution still doesn't work when I tried applying my geometry nodes

I'm working on a project in Blender 4.1 where I'm trying to achieve a "point-cloud" effect on my object. My current node setup is: Distribute Points on Faces > Set Point Radius > Set Position > Group Output. Everything looks great in Blender, but I need to export the object with the geometry nodes function attached.
Whenever I try to apply my modifiers, I get the error: "Evaluated geometry from modifier does not contain a mesh." I've tried the common solutions like using "Realize Instances" before the group output and "Make Instances Real," but they either make the object disappear or still don't let me apply the modifier.
Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a workaround?

Have a look at the spread sheet in the GN editor. There you will see that you have a Point Cloud created by the Distribute Points On Faces node but no mesh data. You can create Instances with an Instance on Points node + an Ico Sphere node. Finally, use the Realize Instances node to create the mesh from the instances.

As @Blunder said, you have created no mesh with your setup. Applying the modifier will only result in a mesh. Even when you have for example a mixed geometry like curves and meshes, applying the modifier will only keep the meshes (if they are no instances). Another thing is if you start with a curve object as base to add a Geometry Nodes modifier. Then it doesn't even matter if the nodetree outputs a mesh, you cannot apply a Geometry Nodes modifier on a curve object - not even when the output would be a curve. Instead of applying you'd have to use Ctrl+A > Visual Geometry to Mesh.
